# Support vector machine classification default threshold

Tags: python, svm, libsvm

```
from sklearn import svm

classifier = svm.SVC(C = 1000 ,kernel = 'rbf',gamma = 0.05)
classifier.fit(attack_list, attack_label)

results = classifier.predict(test_list)
num_correct = (results == test_label).sum()
recall = num_correct / len(test_label)
print ("model accuracy (%): ", recall * 100, "%")
```

is there any way in which I can define the default threshold of SVM (i.e. 0.5) to some other value?

Comment: `classifier. predict_proba(test_list)>threshold`

Comment: the threshold for what?